# Syntax Highlight Confusion / Fail in vim

Tags: javascript, regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

Suppose you have the following line in your .js(x) file and using VIM as your favourite text-editor

`if (foundArray = decodeURIComponent(location.hash).toLowerCase().match(/^#\/([0-9a-zäüöß\-_]+)?\/*$/i)) {`

The `/*` potion of that regex will cause VIM to grey out all of the following lines because it assumes all following symbols are commented out.

Does anybody experience same issues? Any suggestions for workarounds, syntax highlighting scripts/plugins?

**EDIT**

I tried with a minimal vim config (and `vim -u minimalconfig`). Same results...

Contents of minimalconfig:

```
set nocompatible
filetype on
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
syntax enable
set background=dark
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem (both with my `.vimrc` and with `-u NONE`). Is it possibly the colorscheme you're using?

Comment: I don't think that it's the colorscheme. But if you can't reproduce that problem I assume the reason resides in my vim configuration or plugins. I'll try the same with a minimal vim configuration and post the results here.

Comment: I edited my question to verify the problems should be reproducable also with running vim like `vim -u minimalconfig` or `vim -u NONE` (even if the last one is not useful, because there is no syntax highlighting at all wthout any config file)

Comment: Then ... is it because I am using macOS? :-D

Comment: so ... you can confirm that javascript.vim is setting this by the ex command, `:verbose set comments?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a limit of the included JavaScript syntax highlighting. There are alternative JavaScript highlighters which cater for this case:

- [vim-javascript plugin](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript)
- [JavaScript syntax file](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1491)

Those each also make other changes to JavaScript highlighting, so you might want to try them both and see which one you prefer.

Or, rewrite your JavaScript to avoid having `/*` in a regexp literal, for instance by one of:

- Use `{0,}` for zero-or-more, instead of `*`.
- Put the pattern in a string and construct it explicitly with `Regexp('^#/…', 'i')` — the `/*` will then be inside a string constant, which doesn't confuse the highlighter.